# Using generic types in XAML x:Type markup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics

I have the following XAML snippet and I want to include a generic parameter and I can't work out what I need to do?

I guess I'm going to have to created a markup extension to do this but I'm unsure how to get this to work with the x:Type attribute.

```
DataType="{x:Type vm:FooViewModel<Bar>}"
```

Comment: If you're trying to do `DataTemplates` on generic types, that will not work. Create a non-generic version of your type.

Comment: What has "pre .Net 4 Framework" to do with this question? Voting to reopen.

Comment: Is this still not fixed in dotnet 5?

Answer (score 4):

Check the [Generics in XAML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee956431%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to see if it fits your scenario. You'd need to use [`x:TypeArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750476%28v=vs.100%29.aspx); there are however some restrictions that you can check in the linked reference pages.

Comment: Unfortunately `x:TypeArguments` can only be used when creating a new instance - not in `DataType`